# Qt Creator crashes while opeing a file with it's C++ Editor

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I need emergency help from experts
I am using Qt Creator 3.4.1 Based on Qt 5.4.2 in Debian amd64 testing with both lxde and gnome desktop.
I could not open any "cpp", "h" or "pro" file within my qt creator, it crashes while I am using c++ editor or plain text editor to open any of these extentions but I could open my form with ui designer without any problem I try reinstalling the qtcreator and even cleaning qtproject profile folder in my ~/config/qtproject but non of these solve my problem

Comment: Is there any error message on terminal you start Qt Creator from?

Comment: Debian ``testing``. May be a library conflict, try downloading binary package of Qt. Furthermor try running the application running ``strace`` and check your logfiles if something is being logged.

Comment: running in terminal simply gives the "Segmentation fault" message.

Comment: and strace gives the flowing log during the c++ editor gets open
open("/usr/share/icons/breeze_cursors/cursors/wait", O_RDONLY) = 17
open("/home/user/Programs/TestApp/TestApp.pro", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 17
open("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf", O_RDONLY) = 17
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x968} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault

Comment: did you try the binary packages available from qt.io?

Comment: thanks the binaries from qt.io did save me but do you thing the error is because some sort of dependency problem. and still is there any hope to correct the native installed one or I should wait for next update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the binary packages suggestion the qtcreator package from official debian repositories just upgraded to their equivalent binary packages from qt.io (3.5.1) and all the problems get solved. I think it was just a bug and sth related to library confilict.